# Rewriting a threaded Objective-C 'story engine' in CoffeeScript: How to script actions & conditions sequentially without a ton of callbacks?

Tags: objective-c, html, callback, coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

I have been experimenting with porting the underlying 'story engine' of my Objective-C iPhone adventure [Scarlett and the Spark of Life](http://launchingpadgames.com/games/scarlett/) to HTML5 using CoffeeScript (and I am looking into [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/)).

The graphical part can just use DIVs on the DOM — the requirements there are fairly simple. The problematic part is the 'command and control' story-type commands. The ideal is to be able to express high-level story commands — including conditionals — and have them executed **sequentially**. So, for example, in faux-CoffeeScript:

```
scarlett.walkTo(200,300)
scarlett.turnTo(0)
story.wait(0.8)

if interesting
  scarlett.think('Looks interesting.')
else
  scarlett.think('Looks boring.')
```

In Objective-C (this was back when scripting languages like Lua were banned on the App Store), we achieved this by having two threads. The main thread ran cocos2d-phone which handled all the OpenGL calls, animation and other cocos niceties. The 'story' thread handled the command-and-control of the story, and if necessary the thread would sleep, awaiting an `NSCondition` before returning from a function and proceeding to the next call.

It sounds awkward, but it allowed us to express story commands and conditionals in a sequential, natural way, just using normal-looking code. Note that in the example above, the `if` check for the variable `interesting` would be evaluated right before Scarlett says something, *not* at the start of the function. Also, the `walkTo()`, `turnTo()`, `wait()` and `think()` calls will not return until their associated animation, delay or text box is finished back on the main thread.

What I'm struggling with is how to achieve this expressiveness using web technologies. As I see it, my options are:

1. Using a **Web Worker** as the story 'thread'. However, as far as I'm aware, workers can't sleep, and state isn't shared so they can't even perform a busy wait.
2. Using a **callback chain**, probably utilising IcedCoffeeScript's `await` and `defer` keywords to keep the code tidier. Even with those, though, that's a lot of extra line noise.
3. Somehow **evaluate lines** from the story script one-by-one as strings. I can't help feeling that it would be highly problematic.
4. (Similar in some ways to 3.) Write the story commands in a specially-designed **interpreted language**, where the program counter could be stopped and started as needed. It seems like this is unnecessarily re-inventing the wheel.

I can't help feeling like I'm overlooking some really obvious solution, though. Am I looking at this back-to-front, somehow? Is there an acknowledged pattern for *scripting sequential actions and conditionals over time* using actual code, without a mountain of callbacks?

Comment: You could use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/#series) `series` or `waterfall`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing those to my attention. `waterfall` looks like it might work well enough, even if it's a more 'syntaxy' approach than I'd prefer. I'll have a play around and let you know how I get on.